# Lattice Points on a straight line.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-geometry, linear-diophantine-equations

To find: 
The number of lattice points in the 1st quadrant, lying on straight line: $3x+5y = 283.$

-I tried this question a lot many times. The long substitution method becomes tedious. Can you please show a simpler and faster way of solving this question?
I appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try $ 3(an + b)  + 5 (cn + d) = 283 $

Then $ 3an + 5cn = 0 $ and $ 3b + 5d = 283 $

lets try to solve the last equation by noticing that if $b = 1$ then $5d = 280$

, then $d = 56$ .

Now  $3na + 5nc = 0$ , $n(3a + 5b) = 0 $, try $a = 5$ , $c= -3$.

Putting it all together: $3*(5n+1) + 5*(-3n + 56) = 283 $ for all n.

Just a little more work to do if you want the answer in the first quadrant.